# Why is the implication used in this quantifier and not in the other one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Let M(x, y) be “x has sent y an e-mail message” and T(x, y) be “x has telephoned y,” where the
domain consists for all students in your class.

> 1. There is a student in your class who has not received an e-mail message from anyone else in
>      the class and who has not been called by any other student in the class.
>
> ∃x∀y((x $\neq$ y) → (¬M(y, x) ∧ ¬T(y, x)))
>
> 2. Every student in the class has either received an e-mail message or received a telephone call
>      from another student in the class.
>
> ∀x∃y((x $\neq$ y) ∧ (M(y, x) ∨ T(y, x)))

I can't understand why in the first quantifier we used the  → mark and did not directly use the ∧ mark, and if so why didn't use the → mark in the second one. I can't see why should we use different symbols because the sentences that needs to be translated do not show a reason why the first is an `implication` mark and the second is the `conjunction` mark after the (x $\neq$ y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For the 1st sentence

The difference between using conjunction or implication in the first sentence becomes clearer if you consider the two versions of the sentence for a class with only one student. Suppose her name is An.

In this class, $$\exists x\forall y((x\neq y) \land(\neg M(y,x)\land\neg T(y,x)))$$ is false, because there is no $y$ such that $(x\neq y)$. $x$ necessarily is An, and if there is some $y$ such that $(\neg M(y,x)\land\neg T(y,x))$, then necessarily $(y = \text{An})$ too. So, $(x=y)$ and this falsifies the sentence.

On the other hand, $$\exists x\forall y((x\neq y) \to(\neg M(y,x)\land\neg T(y,x)))$$ is true, because it treats $(x \neq y)$ only as a condition and not as a fact that must hold. It says that "if there is a student other than An, then [...]". In this class, it happens that there is no student other than An. Since the condition is not met, the sentence is true no matter the conclusion of the implication.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098601/would-including-the-outside-quantifier-make-more-sense-be-logically-correct) is related and possibly helpful.

### For the 2nd sentence

Consider the two versions of the sentence: $$(\forall x\exists y((x\neq y)\to(M(y,x)\lor T(y,x))))~~\text{and}~~(\forall x\exists y((x\neq y)\land(M(y,x)\lor T(y,x)))).$$ What are the truth values of the two sentences, in a class where everyone has sent an email only to themselves and to no-one else?

Comment: if i am to consider in the 2nd sentence that An is the only student in the class wouldn't it be the same result that the sentence would be false.

Comment: @7210 No, the second sentence is true even for a class with one student. Also in propositional logic, the implication $(F\to T)$ is true (where $T, F$ are the usual truth values).

There's this related question too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020173/nested-quantifiers-implications-or-logical-and
Actually, there are many related questions. Do a search!

Comment: @7210 I hope that by "2nd sentence" we both mean the implication version of the 1st sentence in your post!